# Autogenerate Stub code in C++ to access a webservice?

Tags: c++, web-services, wsdl, stub, auto-generate

I'm chancing my arm with this question. 
I'm looking for a tool which will avoid doing a lot of coding by autogenerating much of the code to access a webservice.

I'm trying to help out someone who uses a 4GL system which doesn't support webservices. However they *can* access a win32 dll - which looks like being the easiest solution. All they need to do is occasionally call a function on a web service and get a result back.

Its been a loooong time since I wrote any C++ and my attempts at doing this have just exposed how rusty I am.

I've played around with the gsoap2 toolkit and MS's svcutil.exe tool for auto generating code.

They do what they are supposed to do but, unlike the add reference tool in visual studio with vb.net or c#.net, these toolkits don't generate a stub access class that I managed to find. 
Instead they generate individual function calls for each method and you have to pass them httpcontexts and a whole load of other stuff - something I don't really want to have to learn how to do for a one off.

What I want to do is mechanical:

- Take the wsdl definition
- AutoGenerate the Webservice access code (done - gsoap2)
- Write/generate a small stub to open the webservice and authenticate using basic authentication and to return an instance of the webservice instance class.
- publish as a dll

The idea being to have a single dll with a single function like 
    getws(username, password, url)
which will return an object which exposes the methods of the webservices - a stub, nothing clever.

I know I'm clutching at straws here but does anyone know of a tool/way to avoid all the mechanical work and to end up with a simple class which I can modify to add authentication.

The webservice has around 30 methods - and I have to expose them all, each has a collection of parameters. Writing a stub class to call the functions generated by gsoap2 would be a *lot* of typing and a nightmare to get to work/debug. Theres got to be a better way.

What I want to do is the equivalent of the .net code below - VS autogenerates the WS code. All I have to do is expose it in my class.

```
 Private Shared oWs As WS.publicws = Nothing

 Public Shared Function GetWS(ByVal Username As String, ByVal password As String, ByVal URL As String) As WS.publicws
    Dim oBinding As New ServiceModel.BasicHttpBinding

    If Not oWs Is Nothing Then Return oWs

    Dim oEndPoint As New ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(URL)
    oBinding.Security.Mode = ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly
    oBinding.Security.Transport.Realm = ServiceModel.HttpClientCredentialType.Basic

    oWS = New WS.publicws (oBinding, oEndPoint)
    oWS.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username
    oWS.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password

    Using scope = New ServiceModel.OperationContextScope(oWs.InnerChannel)
        ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties(System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpRequestMessageProperty.Name) = httpRequestProperty
    End Using

    Return oWs
End Function
```